# How read and print a two column text file containing integers and look for a specific value in the first column?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new to Java and would appreciate any assistance to solve the following problem.
I would like the java program to read and print a two column (integer or double) text file and search for a value in the first column that matches with another parameter within the java code. If the match is found, to print out the corresponding value on the second column. I wrote the following code which can read and print the data in console but I'm unable to use this data in the next code to search for a value in the first column that matches with another parameter. please help,here is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class readfile {
private Scanner s;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    readfile r = new readfile();
    r.openFile();
    r.readFile();
    r.closeFile(); 
}   

public void openFile() {
try {
    s = new Scanner (new File("filename.txt"));

}catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("file not found ");
}


}

public void readFile() {
while(s.hasNext()) {
     String a = s.next();
     String b = s.next();
    System.out.printf("%s  %s\n",a, b);

}
}
public void closeFile() {
s.close();
}
}

// here is the problem!
double a = 0;
double b = 0;
if (para == a[i]) { 
System.out.println("param =" + a[j]);
}else {
System.out.println("It is out of range ");
}
```